# Prime dividing repunit

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Let $ R(n) = \underbrace{111\ldots111}_{\text n\ ones}$. Prove that if a prime number $ p \neq 3 $ divides $ R(n) $ then $ n $ and $ p - 1 $ are not coprime.

So obviously $ R(n) = \frac{10^n - 1}{9}$. Now if $ p $ divides $ R(n) $ then

$$ \frac{10^n - 1}{9} \equiv 0 \pmod p $$

which implies

$$ 10^n - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p $$

$$ 10^n \equiv 1 \pmod p $$

Can we deduce from there that $ GCD(n, p - 1) \neq 1  $? How? Also, why is $ p \neq 3 $ requirement necessary? I suppose "multiplying both sides" by $ 9 = 3^2 $ is somehow relevant, but I'm not sure why... it's not diffucult to come up with a counterexample for $ p = 3 $ case, but I don't know how the proof would account for it.

Answer (score 3):

Use little Fermat $10^{p-1} \equiv 1\bmod p$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get how to go from there... So we have $ 10^{p-1} \equiv 10^n \pmod p $. Is that enough? Why?

Comment: @shooqie Consider the least exponent for which $10^r\equiv 1 \bmod p$. This is $1$ for $p=3$ which is why that doesn't work, doesn't exist for $p=5$ for obvious reasons, but is $\gt 1$ for primes $\gt 5$ because they are not factors of $10^1-1=9$

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem(1)**: 
Let $m$ and $a$ be two integers; 
such that $\gcd(a,m)=1$.
Then there exists a natural number $r$ such that $a^{r} \overset{m}{\equiv} 1$.
The least positive integer $r$ by the above property 
will be called the ***order of $a$ module $m$***;
and we will denote it by $\text{ord}_m(a)$.

**Theorem(2)**: 
Let $m$ and $a$ be two integers; 
such that $\gcd(a,m)=1$.
Suppose that $a^R \overset{m}{\equiv} 1$; then we can conclude that: 
$$\text{ord}_m(a) \mid R \ \  .$$

---

---

**Remark(I)**: 
Let $p\neq3$ (also $p\neq2$ and $p\neq5$ ) be a prime number; 
then $1 < \text{ord}_p(10)$.
**proof**: Suppose on contrary that $ \text{ord}_p(10) = 1$; 
then we must have:
$$ 
10^1 \overset{p}{\equiv} 1 
\Longleftrightarrow p \mid 10-1 
\Longleftrightarrow p =3; $$ 
which has an obvious contradiction with our assumption.

---

**Remark(II)**: 
By little Fermat's theorem we know that 
$$10^{p-1} \overset{p}{\equiv} 1 ;$$ 
now Theorem(2) implies that $\text{ord}_p(10) \mid p-1$.

**Remark(II)**: 
From the assuptuion of the question we know that 
$$10^{n} \overset{p}{\equiv} 1 ;$$ 
now Theorem(2) implies that $\text{ord}_p(10) \mid n$.

---

---

By the last two remarks we can conclude that:

$$1 < \text{ord}_p(10) \mid \text{gcd}(n, p-1).$$

Comment: I wasn't familiar with $ ord_p(n) $ notation, but now that I looked it up, it makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: @shooqie ; My dear shooqie; I have added two theorems and some more explanation, which may help, I hope.